# mongodb upsert with condition

Tags: mongodb, conditional-statements, pymongo, upsert

is there a way with mongodb to bulk upsert but choose what to do when inserting and when updating.
for example:

I have this document in the mongodb:

1. `{name:"david", last_name:"family_name", published:true}`

now arrives a new document that is like this:

2. `{name:"david", last_name:"family_name_changed", published:false}`

now I want to replace the document that is in the DB (document 1)
that will only update the last_name field (or any other field) but I dont want it to update the published field. (ever)

what is the way to do that?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#examples) to update a specific field, for instance:

```
db.<name of your collection>.update(<query>,
{
    $set:
    {
        last_name: <value to set>
    }
}, { multi: true } );
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. but the issue is that I don't want to know which specific fields are needed to be updated... only thing I want to do is to be able to update a whole document but leave few fields ontouched, even if they appear in the new document that i want to update...